# Symfony guard recover from authentication failure

Tags: symfony, security

I have a Symfony application secured by several guard authenticators. Two of them are relevant for this question: one authenticator that checks a user's x509 certificate and if that fails it shows a traditional login form.

I am also using Sonata/FOS user bundle. That bundle checks if the user has a `credentials_expire_at` property and throws a CredentialsExpiredException when `credentials_expire_at <= now()`.

The problem is that it does the check for all authenticators, but the certificate has its own expiry which is not related to the `credentials_expire_at` property of the user.

So we have the following situation: A user accesses the site and supplies a valid certificate. The user's account has the `credentials_expire_at` set in the past, which causes a CredentialsExpiredException to be thrown.

When this happens the `onAuthenticationFailure()` method of the guard gets called which gives me access to the exception and the user. So at that point I know the user and I know why the authentication (wrongfully) failed.

**My question is:** How can I recover from this situation? 
I want symfony to authenticate the user regardless of the exception thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be fairly simple.

The exception is thrown by the UserChecker service (`security.user_checker.main`).

I basically extended the UserChecker provided by Symfony and overrided the `checkPostAuth` method:

```
public function checkPostAuth(UserInterface $user)
{
    try {
        parent::checkPostAuth($user);
    } catch (CredentialsExpiredException $exception) {
        if (!$user->isCertificateLogin()) {
            throw $exception;
        }
    }
}
```

So, this catches the `CredentialsExpiredException` and re-throws it when the user did not login via the Certificate authenticator.

The final step is just to register the service in my `services.yml`:

```
security.user_checker.main:
    class: AppBundle\Security\UserChecker
```

I expected to have to add a CompilerPass for it, but it turns out it is not necessary.